# Create a VBScript that searches for a specific folder in Outlook and creates a rule to move emails to that folder

Tags: vbscript, outlook, directory

I wanted to create a script to be deployed that would connect to outlook and create a rule to move emails based on text in the body to an already created folder. Currently am unable to figure out why I am getting a "Server threw an exception" error on line 47.

Here is my code:

```
'--> Create some constants
Const olRuleReceive = 0

'--> Create some variables
Dim olApp, olSession, olRuleDirectory, newRule, ruleConditions, ruleAction, folderDirectory, newFolder, moveFolder, index, ruleActiona
Dim folderexists


'--> Connect to Outlook
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olSession = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olSession.Logon olApp.DefaultProfileName

' --> Get the rules/folder collection
Set folderDirectory = olSession.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set moveFolder = folderDirectory.Parent

For i = 1 To moveFolder.Folders.Count

    If moveFolder.Folders.item(i).Name = "One" Then
        index = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next

' set moveFolder = moveFolder.Folders.item(index)


Set olRuleDirectory = olSession.DefaultStore.GetRules()

'--> Create a new receive rule
Set newRule = olRuleDirectory.Create("Test", olRuleReceive)

'--> Set the rule's condition to look for a specific word in the subject

Set ruleConditions = newRule.Conditions.Body
With ruleConditions
    .Text = Array("test")
    .Enabled = True
End With

' --> Set the rule's action to move to folder

Set ruleAction = newRule.Actions.MoveToFolder 
 With ruleAction  
 .Enabled = True
 .Folder = moveFolder.Folders(index)  ' this is the part that needs work, a variable needs to be delcared earlier and set to a folder directory. 
 End With


'--> Save the rule
olRuleDirectory.Save False

'--> Disconnect from Outlook
olSession.Logoff
Set ruleConditions = Nothing
Set ruleAction = Nothing
Set newRule = Nothing
Set olRuleDirectory = Nothing
Set olSession = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

'--> Terminate the script
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: So which line exactly throws the error?

Comment: Line 47 -  `.Folder = moveFolder.Folders(index)`

Answer (score 0):

If the folder does not exist, index variable will be uninitialized. 
Note that you don't need to loop through all subfolders to find a folder with a given name - just use `set folder = moveFolder.Folders.Item("One")`.

Comment: I made that change in line 47 but it still throws the same exception. That section now reads.
    `With ruleAction ` 
    `.Enabled = True`
    `.Folder = moveFolder.Folders.Item("One")`